# Im making my api call, but i am not able to return it back to my action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile, react-redux

I have an action creator, it calls my apI(which is its own file), the api works, the action creator works as well. Im able to console.log my response from the api, my issue is returning it to my action creator, where the api function call was made. Thank You.

```js
**ACTION CREATOR**

import * as types from './actionTypes';
import FootballApi from '../api/footballApi';
import { loadLeag_Success } from '.';



//type
export const LOAD_LEAG_GAMES_SUCCESS = 'LEAGUE_GAMES_SUCCESS';

export function loadLeag_Game_Success(data){
    //console.log("before dis", data);
    return;
};


export function getLeaguesGames(idArr, date) { 
    return function(dispatch) {
        Promise.all(FootballApi.getLeaguesGamesAPI(idArr, date))
        .then(() => {
// .        I WANT TO RETURN IT HERE.
               console.log("returned")
               
            })
        //      .catch(error => {
        //         throw(error)
        //    })
    };
}
```

```js
**API FILE**

export default class FootballApi {  
  static getAllLeags() {
    return fetch('https://apifootball.com/api/?APIkey=42f53c25607596901bc6726d6d83c3ebf7376068ff89181d25a1bba477149480&action=get_leagues').then(response => {
         return response.json();
      }).catch(error => {
        return error;
    });
  }

    static getLeaguesGamesAPI(idArr, date){
    
      return idArr.map((id)=>{
        return fetch(`https://apifootball.com/api/?APIkey=42f53c25607596901bc6726d6d83c3ebf7376068ff89181d25a1bba477149480&action=get_events&from=${date}&to=${date}&league_id=${id}`)
        .then(res =>{
          return res.json();
        })
          .then((game) => {
            if(!game.error){
              //console.log("game")
              return game;
          }
        })
      })
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

**ACTION CREATOR**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
import FootballApi from '../api/footballApi';
import { loadLeag_Success } from '.';



const LOAD_LEAG_GAMES_SUCCESS = 'LEAGUE_GAMES_SUCCESS';



export const loadLeag_Game_Success = (data) => {
    console.log(data)// The data will be here
 };


export function getLeaguesGames(idArr, date) { 
    return function(dispatch) {
        Promise.all(FootballApi.getLeaguesGamesAPI(idArr, date))
        .then((data) => {

               dispatch(loadLeag_Game_Success(data));
            })
              .catch(error => {
                 throw(error)
            })
    }; }
```

Comment: Whats up? thanks for the quick response,  but im not passing it to the reducer just yet. im trying to return the data from the api, i edited my code snippet to see where im trying to console.log it.

Comment: I edited my answer aswell , come check it out :) You for got to pass in a "data" inside your .then so the returned response from your api is not assigned to any parameter :)

Comment: so when i do pass data, and console log it. it is not what i want. Gives me back an array that i originally passed into the function.

Comment: Then the problem would be inside your api.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the middleware(like thunk or saga) setup. Your `Promise.All`'s resolve function doesn't take the data parameter.

```
Promise.all(FootballApi.getLeaguesGamesAPI(idArr, date))
    .then((data) => {
        dispatch(loadLeag_Game_Success(data));
    });
```

Comment: ye ai have thunk already set up. Instead of Promise.all what should it be ?

Comment: Promise.all is fine, but you are not passing the `data` variable to the resolve function. replace your `.then(() => ` with `.then((data) =>`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, i removed -

```
   .then((game) => {
        if(!game.error){
         //console.log("game")
      }
     })
```

and put it in my action creator. everything works the way i need it. thanks.

Comment: This is not the right way to do it, once It has an error it should caught in the catch , not proceed with the response.

Comment: i added a .catch to to it. I wasnt getting an error before, i just wasnt able to return. I just had to many returns going on, and tweaked the pages, to  get rid of some.